# How to enable Databricks Connect in Visual Studio Code (Windows)?

Tags: databricks

Enable Databricks Connect along with the Databricks Extension for Visual Studio Code to enhance your data processing capabilities. Databricks Connect allows you to seamlessly access remote Databricks clusters from your local environment, enabling you to execute notebooks and perform data queries as if you were directly connected to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install miniconda
2. Open terminal (Terminal > New Terminal ) [Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CEah.png)
3. Create virtual env:

   conda create -n myenv python=3.11.7

   conda activate myenv
4. Install databricks-connect:

   pip install databricks-connect 14.2.1
5. Install jupyter :

   pip install jupyter
6. Install extension per Databricks in Visual Studio Code [Databricks Connect Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoWtl.png) and Open a folder
7. Configure databricks extension and insert these rows into file Users/USERNAME/.databrickscfg

   [PROFILE_NAME]

   host       = https://adb-XXXXXXXXXXX.X.azuredatabricks.net/

   token      = dapixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Follow the guide how to create personal access token [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth/pat.html#:%7E:text=Databricks%20personal%20access%20tokens%20for%20workspace%20users,-To%20create%20a&text=Click%20Developer.,default%20lifetime%20of%2090%20days.).

8. Choose profile and cluster to run your notebook